# MarkLogic WebDav documents created as binary instead of xml

Tags: webdav, marklogic

I am trying to create a dynamic website using MarkLogic and xQuery as the server side language.

I have created a WebDav server and am using windows explorer to create xml documents within the database, the contents of which are used as some pages content.

When I create xml documents in windows explorer, MarkLogic inserts them as binary documents instead of xml documents, therefore my xquery does not work. Is there any way I can change this, ie a setting within MarkLogic?

If I do `xdmp:document-insert("/example.xml", <a/>)` from within cq it does create an xml document.

Many thanks.

Comment: Apologies if my vocabulary isn't perfect, I'm new to marklogic/xml/xquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the mimetypes in the admin console: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/formats has more on that subject.